# Generating Crema with a manual machine

Tags: espresso, crema

I have a La Pavoni Pro, and noticed that I am a bit inconsistent with the crema. I have read [this other post on crema](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-factors-affect-espresso-crema) and understand the freshness of the beans are the most important part, but I have noticed even with the same beans my crema is not the same. There are a lot of variables with the La Pavoni, tamp, grind, pull, temperature of the machine etc. What variables should I should focus on after considering the freshness of the beans?

Comment: At which pressure does your coffee come out of the machine?

Comment: Between .9 and 1

Comment: Well, you need at least around 6 bar for a crema to appear. Try increasing the pressure.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this machine has a lever that you operate with your arm to create pressure. Radically increasing the pressure means radically increasing the muscle-power required. Also, may want to add weight to the base or clamp it to the table to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that the coffee runs through with at least 6 bar pressure. If your pressure is below that value, you won't get a crema. The recommended pressure for Espresso is 9 bar ± 1, according to the [Italian National Espresso Institute](http://www.espressoitaliano.org/files/File/istituzionale_inei_hq_en.pdf).